# Error : TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: jss, nextjs

To create a Sitecore JSS app, I ran the PowerShell command below :

```
npx create-sitecore-jss --templates nextjs,nextjs-sxa --appName foodorder --hostName sc103.sc  --fetchWith GraphQL
```

However, I encountered the following error:

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bn803\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.15.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\index.js:110:44)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bn803\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.15.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\agent.js:174:29)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bn803\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.15.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\remote.js:7:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
```

I ran the command shown below, but it did not work.

`npm install socks-proxy-agent@latest`

What can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect nvm version `12.15.0`.  I tried your command with node version `18.12.1` with my local and it worked for me. I would recommend trying the latest node version and following the steps below.

1. Install or switch to the latest node version. (`nvm install 18.12.1` or `nvm use 18.12.1`)
2. Install or use the latest JSS CLI globally (`npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli`)
3. Open PowerShell in administrator mode and run command (`npx create-sitecore-jss --templates nextjs,nextjs-sxa --appName foodorder --hostName sc103.sc  --fetchWith GraphQL`)

**Configuration details that worked for me:**

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Sumit, I just wanted to say a quick thank you for your answer to my question  Your solution worked perfectly for me and I really appreciate the time and effort you took to help me out.